# Php mysql transaction not inserting all queries

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I got a problem.
I run a transaction containing 2 queries but only one query is writing on database.. The other is not. How is that possible ? I thought it was either both or none, that's the point of using a transaction right ?

Here is part of my code :

```
mysqli_autocommit($conn, FALSE);
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO my_table_exemple (orderId, packageName, productId, purchaseTime, purchaseState, purchaseToken) 
                             VALUES ('".$_POST["orderId"]."', '".$_POST["packageName"]."', '".$_POST["productId"]."', '".$_POST["purchaseTime"]."', ".$_POST["purchaseState"].", '".$_POST["purchaseToken"]."')");

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE user
                             SET end_date='".$calcEndDate."'
                             WHERE id=".$_POST['user_id']);

/* Validation de la transaction */
if (!mysqli_commit($conn)) {
    $row_array['status'] = "error";
    $row_array['msg'] = "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
} else {
    $row_array['status'] = "success";
    $row_array['msg'] = "Transaction success";
}   
echo json_encode($row_array);
```

This is returning transaction success, updating user table but no record inserted in my_table_exemple.

I have an error on my insert query I guess, I'm going to debug it but I don't want to go ahead without knowing why my transaction is not working the way it is supposed to.

Comment: Please check the engine that is used by your database tables. MyISAM (which at least used to be the default) does not support transactions. If you need transactions, your tables need to be created using e.g. InnoDB.

Comment: That's it mate. You've no idea how I am loving you atm. Didn't ready that anywhere.. Thanks.. ALOT.

Comment: Actually, I was able to change MyISAM to InnoDB on every tables, but it still doesn't work. Has the server a database engine itself used for mysql calls ? Or changing just table engine is enough ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check after each query for any errors - on any error you would rollback, if no errors after all of your queries you would commit. Only the queries with no error will be committed & the commit reports any errors on the commit - not preceding queries.